# If espresso is by definition pressure-brewed coffee, is French press coffee a form of espresso?

Tags: espresso, french-press

I wonder what the pressure difference is?

Comment: A French press for coffee is known in the UK, sometimes, as a "cafeteria" and thought to be the source of the name now used for the restaurant style. However, wikipedia suggests the restaurant got its name another way.

Answer (score 15):

*Espresso* is brewed by passing high pressure water through the coffee at a temperature lower than 100°C (i.e. not boiling water).

[Guidelines from the Istituto Nazionale Espresso Italiano](http://espressoitaliano.org/doc/EIC%20-%20Eng%20-%20LQ.pdf) state that the entry water pressure is 9 ± 1 bar and the entry water temperature is 88 ± 2°C (67 ± 3°C in the cup). The coffe is brewed for 25 ± 2.5 s.

*French press* coffee, instead, is brewed by leaving the coffee for 2-4 minutes at atmospheric pressure (no high pressure involved) in 90-95°C water. The *press* in the name has nothing to do with high pressure, is just describing the fact that you press down the coffee grounds with the piston once it is brewed.

Comment: If you're looking to categorize different brewing methods, French press is considered full immersion brewing.